# How to properly Iterate Enum values in a cycle approach with a given counter in C#

Tags: c#, enums

I did a careful research about this topic but i can't find any solution.

We have a DayOfWeek enum

```
Sunday = 0
Monday = 1
Tuesday = 2
Wednesday = 3
Thursday = 4
Friday = 5
Saturday = 6
```

Now i would like to give a counter of 10 and a random starting point to Friday just an example, I would like to have this output.

```
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
```

Comment: [`int value = counter % 7;Enum.GetName(typeof(DayOfWeek), value);`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4e0fzs.aspx)

Comment: Sir can you clarify your answer?

Comment: I will update it sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mathias R. Jessen mentioned you can do it by `% 7` operation

```
public static IEnumerable<DayOfWeek> GetDaySequence(DayOfWeek startDay, int count)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(i => (DayOfWeek)(((int)startDay + i) % 7));
}
```

**Edit:**

Usage:

```
var days = GetDaySequence(DayOfWeek.Friday, 10).ToList();
```

or

```
foreach (var day in GetDaySequence(DayOfWeek.Friday, 10))
{
    //some logic
}
```

Comment: how can i call this method? im not yet familliar with IEnumerable interface

Comment: i did it by storing the method return value to var and loop it using foreach statement, this solution is quite fast and simple. This solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The generic method solution below allows you to write something like this:

```
foreach (var day in EnumRange(DayOfWeek.Sunday, 12))
{
    Console.WriteLine(day);
}
```

It allows for **non-sequential** enumerations, e.g. the range is defined like:

```
enum NotSequential
{
    Hi = 1,
    Bye = 7,
    AnotherValue = 12
}
```

Using integers will give you better performance, but will break in above case.

Note that there is no `where T : enum` constraint available in C#, so calling `EnumRange<int>(3, 5)` is accepted by the compiler, and will give a runtime exception. The solution does not count backwards, so `count` must be `>= 0`.

```
static IEnumerable<T> EnumRange<T>(T start, int count)
    where T : struct //cannot use where Enum or similar
{
    if (count < 0)
        throw new ArgumentException("Count must be 0 or greater", nameof(count));
    var values = Enum.GetValues(typeof (T)).Cast<T>().ToList();
    var startIndex = values.IndexOf(start);
    if (startIndex == -1) 
        throw new ArgumentException($"Value {start} not defined by enum type {typeof(T)}", nameof(start));

    for (var i = startIndex; i < startIndex + count; i++)
    {
        yield return values[i%values.Count];
    }            
}
```

Comment: Without using linq this logic explain more detail about sequence of enum data. And this has the same output provided by @Kote Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Roelzkie be mindful of enums that do not have their value defined in a straight sequence starting with 0 - that will break his answer.